# Проблема с работой в "униссон" TrackBar-oв при регулировке изображения

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Делаю программу по обработке фото. На начальном этапе столкнулся с проблемой невозможности одновременной работы TrackBar при регулировке яркости, контрастности и цветов. Отрегулировав что-то одно, при переключении на другой TrackBar происходит сброс изображения до первоначального уровня. Подкинул сторонний компонент OrImage - яркость и контрастность регулируются в униссон - цвет - по прежнему нет. Если интересно выложу исходники и пришлю программу. Спасибо заранее. Есть еще много вопросов по программе, но это по мере решения.

Код:

```
unit foto;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Mask, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, ExtDlgs, 
  jpeg, ImgList, DBCtrls, Math, Clipbrd, Spin, Buttons, OrImage, OrImageEditor;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button13: TButton;
    Button14: TButton;
    Button15: TButton;
    Button16: TButton;
    Button17: TButton;
    Button18: TButton;
    Button19: TButton;
    Button20: TButton;
    Button31: TButton;
    Button32: TButton;
    Button33: TButton;
    Button34: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    SavePictureDialog1: TSavePictureDialog;
    OpenPictureDialog1: TOpenPictureDialog;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    Label16: TLabel;
    Label17: TLabel;
    Label18: TLabel;
    GroupBox2: TGroupBox;
    Label19: TLabel;
    Label20: TLabel;
    Label21: TLabel;
    CheckBox2: TCheckBox;
    GroupBox3: TGroupBox;
    Label22: TLabel;
    Label23: TLabel;
    Label24: TLabel;
    CheckBox3: TCheckBox;
    TrackBar5: TTrackBar;
    TrackBar6: TTrackBar;
    TrackBar7: TTrackBar;
    Label25: TLabel;
    Label26: TLabel;
    Label27: TLabel;
    Label28: TLabel;
    Label29: TLabel;
    Label30: TLabel;
    Bevel1: TBevel;
    Bevel2: TBevel;
    Bevel3: TBevel;
    Bevel4: TBevel;
    Bevel6: TBevel;
    SpinEdit1: TSpinEdit;
    SpinEdit2: TSpinEdit;
    SpinEdit3: TSpinEdit;
    SpinEdit4: TSpinEdit;
    SpinEdit5: TSpinEdit;
    SpinEdit6: TSpinEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Edit6: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    OrImage1: TOrImage;
    Bevel5: TBevel;
    OrImage2: TOrImage;
    OrImage3: TOrImage;
    OrImage4: TOrImage;
    OrImage5: TOrImage;
    OrImage6: TOrImage;
    TrackBarBrightness1: TTrackBar;
    TrackBarContrast1: TTrackBar;

    procedure Button13Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button33Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button34Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OrImageDblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TrackBarBrightnessChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TrackBarContrastChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OrImage1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OrImage2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OrImage3DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OrImage4DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OrImage5DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure TrackBarChange(Sender: TObject);

    private
    { Private declarations }

    public
    { Public declarations }
    OrImage: TOrImage;
    procedure UpdateEffects;

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  const
    MaxPixelCount   =  32768;

type
    pRGBArray  =  ^TRGBArray;
    TRGBArray  =  ARRAY[0..MaxPixelCount-1] OF TRGBTriple;

function Min(a, b: integer): integer;
function Max(a, b: integer): integer;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

const strTrueORFalse: array[Boolean]of string = ('false','true');

 procedure TForm1.Button13Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    q : integer;
  begin
  if (openpicturedialog1.Execute) and (openpicturedialog1.FileName <> '') then
    try
      for q := 0 to openpicturedialog1.Files.Count - 1 do
        case q of
          0:begin
                  OrImage1.Picture.LoadFromFile(openpicturedialog1.Files.Strings[q]);
                  OrImage1.PictureOriginal := OrImage1.Picture;
            end;
          1:begin
                  OrImage2.Picture.LoadFromFile(openpicturedialog1.Files.Strings[q]);
                  OrImage2.PictureOriginal := OrImage2.Picture;
            end;
          2:begin
                  OrImage3.Picture.LoadFromFile(openpicturedialog1.Files.Strings[q]);
                  OrImage3.PictureOriginal := OrImage3.Picture;
            end;
          3:begin
                  OrImage4.Picture.LoadFromFile(openpicturedialog1.Files.Strings[q]);
                  OrImage4.PictureOriginal := OrImage4.Picture;
            end;
          4:begin
                  OrImage5.Picture.LoadFromFile(openpicturedialog1.Files.Strings[q]);
                  OrImage5.PictureOriginal := OrImage5.Picture;
            end;
          5:begin
                  OrImage6.Picture.LoadFromFile(openpicturedialog1.Files.Strings[q]);
                  OrImage6.PictureOriginal := OrImage6.Picture;
            end;
        end;
    except
        ShowMessage('Ошибка!');
    end;

  end;

 procedure TForm1.formCreate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 Label20.Caption := '0';
 Label17.Caption := '0';
 TrackBar5.Position := 0;
 Label23.Caption := '0';
 TrackBar6.Position := 0;
 Label29.Caption := '0';
 TrackBar7.Position := 0;
 Label30.Caption := '0';
 end;

  //procedure TForm1.OrImageClick(Sender: TObject);
procedure TForm1.TrackBarChange(Sender: TObject);
var i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, e, f, r, t, g, h, RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue : integer;
    OrigRow, DestRow: pRGBArray;
begin
  RedValue := TrackBar5.Position;
  GreenValue := TrackBar6.Position;
  BlueValue := TrackBar7.Position;

  if RedValue <= 0 then Label23.Caption := IntToStr(RedValue)
  else Label23.Caption := Format('+%d', [RedValue]);
  if GreenValue <= 0 then Label29.Caption := IntToStr(GreenValue)
  else Label29.Caption := Format('+%d', [GreenValue]);
  if BlueValue <= 0 then Label30.Caption := IntToStr(BlueValue)
  else Label30.Caption := Format('+%d', [BlueValue]);

  for i := 0 to OrImage1.Picture.Height - 1 do
  begin
    OrigRow := OrImage1.PictureOriginal.Bitmap.ScanLine[i];
    DestRow := OrImage1.Picture.Bitmap.ScanLine[i];
    for j := 0 to OrImage1.Picture.Width - 1 do
    begin
      if RedValue > 0 then
        DestRow[j].rgbtRed := Min(255, OrigRow[j].rgbtRed + RedValue)
      else
        DestRow[j].rgbtRed := Max(0, OrigRow[j].rgbtRed + RedValue);
      if GreenValue > 0 then
        DestRow[j].rgbtGreen := Min(255, OrigRow[j].rgbtGreen + GreenValue)
      else
        DestRow[j].rgbtGreen := Max(0, OrigRow[j].rgbtGreen + GreenValue);
      if BlueValue > 0 then
        DestRow[j].rgbtBlue := Min(255, OrigRow[j].rgbtBlue + BlueValue)
      else
        DestRow[j].rgbtBlue := Max(0, OrigRow[j].rgbtBlue + BlueValue);
    end;
  end;

  OrImage1.Repaint;
  //OrImage1.UpdateEffects;
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateEffects;
 begin
  if OrImage1<> nil then with OrImage1 do
  begin
    TrackBarBrightness1.Position:=PicBrightness;
    TrackBarContrast1.Position:=PicContrast;
  end;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if OrImage1<>nil then
  UpdateEffects;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.TrackBarBrightnessChange(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if OrImage1=nil then Exit;
  OrImage1.PicBrightness:=TrackBarBrightness1.Position;
  Label17.Caption:=' '+IntToStr(OrImage1.PicBrightness)+' ';

 end;

 procedure TForm1.TrackBarContrastChange(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if OrImage1=nil then Exit;
  OrImage1.PicContrast:=TrackBarContrast1.Position;
  Label20.Caption:=' '+IntToStr(OrImage1.PicContrast)+' ';

 end;

 procedure TForm1.Button33Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 SavePictureDialog1.Execute
 end;

 procedure TForm1.Button34Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 Close
 end;

 procedure TForm1.OrImageDblClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   ClipBoard.Clear;
   ClipBoard.Open;
   ClipBoard.Assign(OrImage1.Picture);
   ClipBoard.Close;
   Form2.Showmodal;
 end;
 procedure TForm1.OrImage1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   ClipBoard.Clear;
   ClipBoard.Open;
   ClipBoard.Assign(OrImage2.Picture);
   ClipBoard.Close;
   Form2.Showmodal;
 end;
 procedure TForm1.OrImage2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   ClipBoard.Clear;
   ClipBoard.Open;
   ClipBoard.Assign(OrImage3.Picture);
   ClipBoard.Close;
   Form2.Showmodal;
 end;
 procedure TForm1.OrImage3DblClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   ClipBoard.Clear;
   ClipBoard.Open;
   ClipBoard.Assign(OrImage4.Picture);
   ClipBoard.Close;
   Form2.Showmodal;
 end;
 procedure TForm1.OrImage4DblClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   ClipBoard.Clear;
   ClipBoard.Open;
   ClipBoard.Assign(OrImage5.Picture);
   ClipBoard.Close;
   Form2.Showmodal;
 end;
 procedure TForm1.OrImage5DblClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   ClipBoard.Clear;
   ClipBoard.Open;
   ClipBoard.Assign(OrImage6.Picture);
   ClipBoard.Close;
   Form2.Showmodal;
 end;
 function Min(a, b: integer): integer;
begin
  if a < b then result := a
  else result := b;
end;

function Max(a, b: integer): integer;
begin
  if a > b then result := a
  else result := b;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Вы бы показали обработчик, висящий на TrackBar-е.

Comment: за такое платить денюжку надо))

Answer (score 1):

Я однажды писал графический редактор, и когда регулировал яркость (шум, размытие), то у меня была кнопка "Применить" (у меня там всё на отдельной вкладке регулировалось). Можно и без кнопки обойтись, если перешёл курсор на другой элемент управления (например, на событии OnExit компонента TrackBar) сохранять настройки изображения в Image, так они не должны сбрасываться.